# issue of race condition b/w direct code and jquery handlers in client side JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this code valid/correct

```
var items = $(".items");    // when would items be properly populated, at dom.ready()??
var itemsHrefs = []; // direct JS code

prepareItemsList();  **// direct JS code**

**// could be the case that items array is not populated yet ???**
function prepareItemsList() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    var plElement = items.eq(i);
    itemsHrefs.push (plElement.attr('href'));
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. When would items variable be properly created. I assume dom.ready()??
2. Should I put execution of prepareItemsList() inside a document.ready handler to be correct?

NOTE: When I tried doing 2. above, I ran into different issues

Comment: Please edit this question and give it a meaningful title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code that works with the DOM in a `$(document).ready()` callback. If you try to work with the DOM before it's ready, your code will not work properly (or at all).

It's sometimes confusing to keep only a portion of the code in the callback, so I usually just wrap everything jQuery-related in it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items_hrefs = $('.items').map(function() {
        return this.href;
    }).get();
});
```